# Is the Face of Boe’s death linked to the destruction of Earth?

Tags: doctor-who, torchwood, jack-harkness

> At the end of Miracle Day, Jack Harkness’ immortality gets restored through the Blessing ([The Blood Line](//tardis.wikia.com/wiki/The_Blood_Line_(TV_story))). Also, there are strong hints that Harkness will eventually become the Face of Boe ([Last of the Time Lords](//tardis.wikia.com/wiki/Last_of_the_Time_Lords)). Now, the Blessing arguably ceases with the destruction of earth ([The End of the World](//tardis.wikia.com/wiki/The_End_of_the_World_(TV_story))) and a few decades afterwards the Face of Boe is dying from old age ([New Earth](//tardis.wikia.com/wiki/New_Earth_(TV_story))), which he eventually does another few decades later ([Gridlock](http://tardis.wikia.com/wiki/Gridlock)).

This suggests the hypothesis that after the events of Miracle Day, Jack’s immortality was granted by the Blessing. Hence he becomes mortal with the destruction of earth.

Is there any further evidence supporting this hypothesis (in-universe or out-of-universe)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Blessing did not give Jack immortality.  Jack's immortality stemmed from Rose being unable to control her powers and reviving him but accidentally making him immortal.  All The Blessing did was undue his immortality and give it to the rest of the world.  The last episode just undid what The Blessing had done, and Jack got back his original immortality.  Also in universe The Blessing only affected Earth.

http://tardis.wikia.com/wiki/The_Blessing

> The Blessing was the focus of a morphic field matrix that encompassed all humankind, and the Families were able to alter it by introducing Jack's blood on both sides of the fissure.

The Face of Boe was known throughout the universe which means that they traveled far beyond the Earth which would mean that The Blessing had no affect on them.